# Illegal return type using java lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8

I saw this example in a Java8 book and it stated that:

> it is illegal for a lambda expression to return a value in some
>   branches but not for others. For example the following is illegal:

```
(int x) -> { if(x >= 0) return 1; }
```

it says it's illegal but doesn't explain why.
Can anyone tell me why is it illegal?

(Note: book "Java SE8 for the really impatient")

Comment: What should happen if `x < 0`? This is why it is illegal.

Comment: @Tunaki: Yes, like in a regular method; but in lambdas the return keyword is not mandatory. Right?

Comment: Your lambda is [value-compatible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2) here since it returns a value. So it should return a value for all cases. Only lambdas that are void-compatible can omit returning a value. This is really the same as a method body.

Comment: Then this is no duplicate question. This is a specific java8 issue. This is no method "problem" like the (other/linked) question.

Comment: Well it is the same core issue, not specific to Java 8. A block returning a value must do it for all branches.

Comment: Ok. Now I see what they mean by 'branches' (logical ones). You are right. Thanks for the answers ;)

Comment: You are right in that you are not required to put a `return` statement in it. E.g., you could write `(int x) -> { if(x >= 0) return 1; for(;;); }` if hanging forever in the case `x<0` is an option for you. This still matches the question in [@Tunakis first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573342/illegal-return-type-using-java-lambdas#comment62634009_37573342): “What should happen if `x < 0`?”. You could also throw an exception, if you like. But you have to tell, the compiler can’t guess.

Comment: And to unleash the beauty of lambda expressions, you can indeed write your lambda expression without a `return` statement, e.g. `x -> x>=0? 1: defaultValue`. You see the pattern, you still have to tell the value for each logical branch.